# What is form.visible_fields in Django and how do I index into it?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Sometimes I have the need to render a particular Django form field in a particular way. I would like to be able to access this field and only this field in order to customize its rendering in my template.

I know, for example, that I can do something like this:

```
<!--Access the form field at index 2-->
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
        <!--Render my form field the way that I want to-->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Intuitively, I would expect to be able to do something like `{{ form.visible_fields[2] }}` or perhaps `{{ form.visible_fields['field_name'] }}`.

Unfortunately, my various attempts at the above have all failed and so I'm left wondering if this is possible. Any advice?

Comment: Firstly, why don't you print it in the view or template if you want to know what it is? And secondly, that syntax is simply not valid in Django templates, which has nothing to do with that attribute in particular.

Comment: I did! I'll add the result to the question. I assumed that was the case for the syntax. I guess I was just wondering (hoping) that there was a good way to do something like this within the confines of the template language.

Comment: Also, just realized that you meant printing from the view. I know this is basic, but how do I print from a view? I've added the print statement but i can't just run the python file.

Comment: The point is, it's a list, and in Django templates you always use dot notation: so `{{ form.visible_fields.2 }}`. Although I can't understand why you want to do this when you can just do `{{ form.field_name }}`.

Comment: Makes sense. I actually didn't know that I could do form.field_name, so I think that's what I was ultimately looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields) you should be able to something like this:

```
{# Include the hidden fields #}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
{# Include the visible fields #}
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Right, but my goal is to avoid having to use a forloop and an if statement to access  a particular form field.

Comment: You should be able to do `{{ form.visible_fields.0 }}`